# Dockerfile set to start wordpress container with php and mysql, starts mariadb instead

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, docker, mariadb

So I have a docker server running ubuntu and my local environment (docker running on MacBook Pro hardware & OSX) was running fine 2 days ago. It had a build issue so I tried to rebuild, but now I've spent the past 12 hours trying to get it to build. In every result, the closest I get is it'll start up the server, but it'll start it with MariaDB instead of MySQL. Which results in WordPress just spitting out the "cannot connect to database" error.

This is what the logs say as the image spools up:

```
Step 6/10 : RUN find /var/lib/mysql -type f -exec touch {} \; && \
    service mysql start && \
    mysql -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('{redacted}');" && \
    mysql -u root -pmysql -e "DROP DATABASE if exists theTable; DROP DATABASE if exists secondTable; CREATE DATABASE theTable; CREATE DATABASE secondTable;" && \
    mysql -u root -pmysql theTable < /code/devdb/theTable.sql && \
 ---> Running in e1205f2fa886
Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld.
```

I think the issue lies in an upgrade to php7.2 that happened months ago, but I don't think the dockerfile was ever updated. I tried using the latest official php7.2-fpm image, but then the apache commands were throwing errors. So I tried php7.2-apache, but then php was throwing errors saying "gd" was not installed. But then I tried adding it using

```
apt-get install php7.2-xxx
```

and also tried by using

```
rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/no-debian-php && \
docker-php-ext-install {XXX}
```

Then I got it to at least start the server with

```
wordpress:php7.2-apache
```

and

```
mobingi/ubuntu-apache2-php7:7.2
```

and the server starts, but it starts a MariaDB image!

I also got the server to start using

```
binhle410/php7.2-fpm
```

But something even weirder happened, every page only displayed the php code. Like the browser just echo'd the header php file on each page.

Here's the relevent DockerFile:

```
FROM wordpress:php7.2-apache

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data && \
    apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && \
    apt-get -y install default-mysql-server git && \
    a2enmod expires && a2enmod headers && a2enmod rewrite && \
    sed -i -e 's/None/All/g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf && \
    mkdir -p /var/www/html && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN mkdir -p /code
COPY ./devdb /code/devdb

RUN find /var/lib/mysql -type f -exec touch {} \; && \
    service mysql start && \
    mysql -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('{redacted}');" && \
    mysql -u root -pmysql -e "DROP DATABASE if exists theTable; DROP DATABASE if exists secondTable; CREATE DATABASE theTable; CREATE DATABASE secondTable;" && \
    mysql -u root -pmysql theTable < /code/devdb/theTable.sql && \
```

And docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./:/code
      - /var/lib/mysql
      - ./tests:/var/www/html/tests
      - ./vendor:/var/www/html/vendor
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: {redacted}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: theTable
      DOCKER_DEBUG: 1
```

The results I'm getting are that when I run docker-compose up --build, it spools up the server, but starts a mariadb instead of mysql db which wordpress then can't link to. The docker image should start a mysql server using a sql file I have and not a mariadb image.

This is what the console outputs:

```
Step 6/10 : RUN find /var/lib/mysql -type f -exec touch {} \; && \
    service mysql start && \
    mysql -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('{redacted}');" && \
    mysql -u root -pmysql -e "DROP DATABASE if exists theTable; DROP DATABASE if exists secondTable; CREATE DATABASE theTable; CREATE DATABASE secondTable;" && \
    mysql -u root -pmysql theTable < /code/devdb/theTable.sql && \
 ---> Running in e1205f2fa886
Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out guys

```
FROM mobingi/ubuntu-apache2-php7:7.2

# disable interactive functions
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive​

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data && \
    apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && \
    apt-get -y install curl zip unzip php7.2-zip mysql-server git && \
    a2enmod expires && a2enmod headers && a2enmod rewrite && \
    sed -i -e 's/None/All/g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf && \
    mkdir -p /var/www/html && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN mkdir -p /code
COPY ./devdb /code/devdb
RUN find /var/lib/mysql -type f -exec touch {} \; && \
    service mysql start && \
    mysql -e "SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD({redacted});" && \
    mysql -u root -pmysql -e "DROP DATABASE if exists theTable; DROP DATABASE if exists secondTable; CREATE DATABASE theTable; CREATE DATABASE secondTable;" && \
    mysql -u root -pmysql theTable < /code/devdb/theTable.sql && \
    mysql -u root -pmysql secondTable < /code/devdb/secondTable.sql 
...
```

worked